# Choosing right equipment for the Test Fixture

Tags: serial, plc, production-testing

I'm planning to build a "Test Fixture" which tests PCB via PC that reads data from the I/O module. And since i want this project to be flexible to the PCB change, my preference gone towards to the PLC ( I can easly extend the I/O number etc.). Using similar modules like "Analog Discovery 2" is seems not preferable cause of limited I/O. So I want to ask your advice on this subject. What can I use to read data from the tested PCB and communicates with PC (I don't want to build a PCB for it, since it seems not flexible)?

Comment: Have you looked at national instruments ni.com? they are one of many that make equipment specifically designed to do what you want. I used them many years ago and could not have been happier with the results. I believe they will also do one of a kind if you need that.

Comment: I have looked them but i was planning do this project more available in price aspect. If i cant find any option i will look the national instrument.